# Jira Cloud Smart Commit - change time synchronization

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I have problem with Jira Cloud and Bitbacket. When I make smart commit - Jira only synchronize data commits with 60 min interval. Can I change this setting in Jira Cloud?

May be anybody had such problem? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that in cloud instances web hook from Bitbucket is responsible to trigger sync. I believe Benjamin Morgan replied to similar questions in Atlassian issue tracking. I would recommend you to take a look at it ([here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSWCLOUD-14345)).

However, since Atlassian Cloud instances change regularly it's difficult to verify if it's still a valid configuration or not.

Comment: This is also good link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/slow-appearing-commits-from-bitbucket-or-github-in-jira-779160823.html